# .dst file reader for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, dst-embroidery

I want to read and display .dst file that is use for embroidery making. I have tried searching over net for library and framework but found nothing, also I have tried to open the file as string using NSData but it not able to read that. Any idea how can i read .dst file extension file in ios.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can read DST files as NSData, but then you have to parse the data and create stitches on your own. Take this info as a starting point: http://www.achatina.de/sewing/main/DST.HTM, AFAIK there's no library / framework available to the public.

Answer (score 1):

libembroidery is the underlying library that is used and developed by Embroidermodder 2. It handles over 45 different embroidery specific formats (including DST) as well as several non-embroidery specific vector formats.

It is open source and you can find it here:
https://github.com/Embroidermodder/Embroidermodder/tree/master/libembroidery